# logic required to insert multiple Records from 1 record in excel Sheet in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

In my assignment , I have to develop code to read records from excel Sheet and insert the records into database in defined manner.

I have to read records from Sheet containing 5 columns and create 4 (No of Values in Sheet row -1) records into database uisng values in Sheet row.

For example my excel Sheet contains 5 columns and contains following Records

row 1 (Header) : Column1,  Column2,  Column3,  Column4,  Column5
row 2 : 
5,  4,  3,  2,  1

Now i am able to read the Records from excel sheet using jxl library but i am stuck in creating logic to insert one excel sheet record in DB as 4 records as shown in below example

row 1 : 1 2 
row 2 : 2 3 
row 3 : 3 4  
row 4 : 4 5

I am not able to formulate logic on how to insert records in DB in above fashion i.e 1 record in Excel Sheet will create 4 records in DB in above manner.

Also there is one more case in above scenario

if any column don't have Value then it should take next columns values means 
for example

row 1 (Header): Column1,  Column2,  Column3,  Column4,  Column5
row 2 : 
5,  ,  3,  2,  1

Then i should create 3 rows as follows

row1 : 1,2 
row2 : 2,3 
row3 : 3,5

kindly help me understand how i can achieve above scenario using java.

pseudo code or algorithm will also be helpful

Database used : Oracle

Answer (score 0):

If you pass your rows straight to the DB, then this query should be good:

```
with w(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, id) as
(
   select 5,  4,  3,  2,  1, 10 from dual
   union all
   select 5,  null,  3,  2,  1, 20 from dual
   union all
   select null, 4,  null,  2,  1, 30 from dual
),
w2 as
(
  select decode(c1, null, 1, 0) + decode(c2, null, 1, 0) + decode(c3, null, 1, 0) + decode(c4, null, 1, 0) + decode(c5, null, 1, 0) nb_nulls,
         coalesce(c5, c4, c3, c2, c1) v5,
         coalesce(c4, c3, c2, c1) v4,
         coalesce(c3, c2, c1) v3,
         coalesce(c2, c1) v2,
         c1 v1,
         id
  from w
)
select v5, v4, nb_nulls, id from w2 where nb_nulls < 4
union all
select v4, v3, nb_nulls, id from w2 where nb_nulls < 3
union all
select v3, v2, nb_nulls, id from w2 where nb_nulls < 2
union all
select v2, v1, nb_nulls, id from w2 where nb_nulls < 1
order by id
;
```

Result:

```
V5  V4  NB_NULLS    ID
4   5   0   10
1   2   0   10
3   4   0   10
2   3   0   10
1   2   1   20
2   3   1   20
3   5   1   20
1   2   2   30
2   4   2   30
```

I just added the `id` field to explain the concept better. For every row, I count the number of null values, then right-align the values with `coalesce`. Then you just have to use a simple `where` to select the correct lines.